# Integration of different works by different people in moodle

Tags: database, version-control, integration, moodle

We are developing a moodle site. We are a group of 5 people and each one is working on different module locally. But now we wwant to integrate the work of all in one machine or server. Is there any way to version control it or integrate it as the databse of each one is different because of different data. Please provide the solutuion as early as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear as to whether you are separately working on the *content* of the site or the *code* for the new site, so I will attempt to answer both questions.

For *content* the easiest way to integrate it all together into one site is to use the Moodle backup and restore mechanism ( http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Course_backup ) - backup each of the courses and then restore them onto the main site. If you have a lot of courses to transfer, then it may make more sense to write some code to automate certain aspects of this, but that can be quite a bit of work, so usually it is easier to just manually do the backup and restore.

For *code* the answer is Git. All the core Moodle code is version controlled via git. Make sure that each developer is working with their own clone of your main git repository (you can find the core Moodle repository at . Once they have committed each of their changes, then they can be pushed (to a central repository) or pulled to your production site. Read more at http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Git_for_developers

Note that if the code for each module has been written with the proper DB installation / upgrade code ( http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Upgrade_API ) then it should simply be possible to take the code from each of the developed modules, put them together into one codebase and then create a fully-working fresh install. Once you have that, you should be able to use backup and restore to transfer any required courses from the development servers to the live server.

Comment: Thank you for explaining both the parts. Actually each one of us has installed moodle locally on our respective machine using xampp. Now each one of us has different database entries i.e., ibdata1 file is different. Some have additional table added because of some extra plugins. The guy working with design part have different theme than us; so his database differs. So should we start from scratch with Git or we can forward our changes to Git now?

Comment: And how about Git in windows? Will it be good working with Git using windows. Or Linux?

Comment: I suggest you set up a central git repository for your code (cloned from the official Moodle repository). Everyone then clones from that repository, adds their local changes and then pushes to the central repo (note, if you are going to 'push' the central repo must be 'bare', otherwise, you can 'pull' into the central repo from the developers clones). If the code has been written correctly (with the DB upgrade code mentioned in my answer), then pull the code, log in as an admin on your local site, and you should have all the relevant fields/tables added to your database.

Comment: Git does work in Windows (and many Moodle devs use it), but I mostly use Linux for development, so I can't offer detailed advice about that.

Comment: What can you tell about Team Foundation Server (TFS) and moodle? Is it a workable solution if Git is not used. And how if you have any idea? Please. @davosmith

Comment: I know nothing about TFS. Git will allow you to integrate your local changes directly with the git-managed changes from Moodle HQ. Don't use something else unless you can come up with a very good reason to do so.